# Querying a large number of posts including their custom fields data

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, svg

I'm building a SVG map separated into about 200 regions. For each region there are attributes that describe it, as well as a region ID. These regions are just polygons in the SVG.

I setup a custom post type so that the data associated with these regions could be added in the dashboard, and upon a user clicking a region, its ID would be used to retrieve the associated its data and display it in a tooltip via AJAX.

This is working fine and dandy, but I would like to improve on it by injecting the attributes to the region polygons as data-attributes once the SVG is loaded. This would allow me to tweak how the polygons look (e.g. color-code) dependent on their attributes without resorting to the query / tooltip method.

My question is, when retrieving custom fields alongside so many posts (~200), will this cause performance concerns? Is there an alternative way of structuring this information so that it can be managed in the dashboard?

To re-iterate, there are roughly 200 items that each have 10 custom fields, and I want to retrieve all of this data on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of caching plugins that may work for you, or build the data on the admin side [when posts are added/updated](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and save it in [an option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).